# Unable to type in UITextfield in iphone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my application, I have sign in page but sometimes in `textfield` unable to type.

It happens rarely; I am creating textfield programmatically and already set property for `userUnteractionEnabled`.

Comment: Share all code how you add textfield...

Comment: write this code in your viewDidLoad function [self.view bringSubviewToFront:txtField];

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the issue in iOS 5 or xcode 4.2, i have faced same issue, if we use resignFirstResponder and becomeFirstResponder in same loop some time we would face this kind of issue, to fix this you may follow below code. this may help you

**becomeFirstResponder**

```
[textfield performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Comment: I am not sure whether its iOS 5 or Xcode 4.2 i faced same issue.